# How to fix vertical spacing variations in different browsers?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I have a little piece of code that is rendering with fairly different vertical spacing in firefox, chrome, and ie9 on my win7 machine.

```
<div id="main-compo">
                <div id="divisions" class="transparent">
                    <p><a href="#">p1</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">p2</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">p3</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">p4</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">p5</a></p>
                    <p><a href="#">p6</a>
                    <p style="border-bottom: none;"><a href="#">p7</a></p>
                </div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erea/96KBC/

I've been working on it for over an hour and I still have no idea why. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Use a reset style sheet. http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Tried that exact reset.css without making any changes to it and it really messed up the site. I will try it in the jsfiddle and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out `line-height` was the problem.

Added this and everything is prefect now.

```
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
p {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```